# master detail app crashes instantly when using push segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue, ipad

First of all, if this is, somehow, a dup post, feel free to point me to the correct one because I have not found it after hours of searching.

I am using a MasterDetail viewController in my app, which for the first week or so of development, had no additional ViewVontrollers or segues other than the default. I wrote my main code, and the Master and Detail viewController are working perfectly. As soon as I added another VC with a push segue from the Detail View, my app crashes instantly. This is the error :

`***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason '-[UINavigationController setPlayer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...'` and then a bunch of hex.

In the AppDelegate.m, if I comment out this line:

`rightViewController.delegate = rightViewController`

Then the app will start up and the push segue will work, but now, obviously, if I were to select a cell in the MasterView, it would crash giving this error:

`***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason '-[UINavigationController selectedPlayer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...'` and then a bunch of hex.

Here is all of the code that I think is relevant:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "LeftViewController.h"
#import "RightViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *leftNavController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    LeftViewController *leftViewController = (LeftViewController *)[leftNavController topViewController];
    RightViewController *rightViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

    Player *selectedPlayer = [[leftViewController preclears]objectAtIndex:0];
    [rightViewController setPlayer:selectedPlayer];

    leftViewController.delegate = rightViewController;
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate.   See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

**LeftViewController.m (part)**

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //Re-fetch the feed from the Postgres Database when a user selects an entry

    [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:@"http://myurl" completion:^(NSDictionary *json, JSONModelError *err) {
    NSError* error = nil;
    _feed = [[PostgresFeed alloc] initWithDictionary:json error:&error];

    //Print the data fethced to NSLog in JSON format

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotification" object:nil userInfo:[[json objectForKey:@"player"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}];

Player *selectedPlayer = [_players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (_delegate) 
    {
        [_delegate selectedPlayer:selectedPlayer];
    }
}
```

So, I am doing something wrong, but I can not figure out what it is. I have done a lot of googling and have not found an answer yet. In case someone wants to know, I am new to iOS and Obj C, and the MasterDetail app was based off of the Ray Wenderlich tutorial for iPad SplitViews. I have also checked out some of the Scott Sherwood tutorials on segues, but have not found any answers there.

Let me know if any more code is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

```
-[UINavigationController setPlayer:]: unrecognized selector ...
```

indicates that

```
RightViewController *rightViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

returns a `UINavigationController` instance, and not a `RightViewController` instance as
expected. The solution depends on the structure of your view controllers hierarchy.
It may be that you have to proceed similar to the left view controller:

```
UINavigationController *rightNavController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
RightViewController *rightViewController = (RightViewController *)[rightNavController topViewController];
```

Comment: @CaptJak: I am glad that it helped. Unfortunately, I do not have links to tutorials.